# Click events on Multiple divs and elements

Tags: jquery, onclick

Im brand new to jQuery and i've hit a block!, 1st ill decsribe me document and what im hoping to achieve.

I have a set of buttons (6) that ech call in a different div with content using the .fadeIn event. when the document loads, the initial div is visible aht the other 5 are hidden using `<div style="display:none".....>`.

What i need help with is how to use the .click function on each button to hide ALL div exect the one clicked by the user. I hope this makes sense. my code as far as i could understand looks line this:

```
$(document.ready(function() {
    $("#my1stbutton").click(function() {
        $("#my1stdiv").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

this is successfully showing "#my1stdiv" but after that, i dont know how to code such that when i click on "#my2ndbutton" the action hides "#my1stdiv" and displays "#my2nddiv" and so on.

Please help. Otherwise im loving jQuery...

regards

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to give your elements classes as well as IDs.  This means you can select multiple elements in one go.  So your links could have the class `button` and your `div` elements the class `section`.

You should also know that, within an event handler, the variable `this` is the element that was clicked on.

First, we will find the element with the class `section` that is visible.  We can then use the function [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/), which tells us which element in the set was clicked on, and use this to work out which element to show.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function() { // when a button is clicked
        $('.section:visible').fadeOut(); // hide the visible section
        $('.section').eq($(this).index()).fadeIn(); // show the section that has the equivalent position in the set to the link 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
$("#button1").click(){
    $("#div1").fadeIn();
    $("#div2").css("display", "none");
    $("#div3").css("display", "none");
    ..all other divs you want to hide
});
```

you can also do .hide() on the divs

```
$("#button1").click(){
    $("#div1").fadeIn();
    $("#div2").hide();
    $("#div3").hide();
    ..all other divs you want to hide
});
```

Comment: thank you so much for the assist, will try this now.one more question...so when i appy the script for the other buttons, do i need to terminate/close the previous using });... i.e.:$("#button1").click(){
    $("#div1").fadeIn();
    $("#div2").hide();
    $("#div3").hide();    }); then the next button?

Comment: for something similar to what your looking for go to http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/ its pretty much the same though...hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $(this).parent('div').fadeIn();
    $('div').not($(this).parent('div')).toggle('fast');
});
```

EDIT:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var index = $('button').index(this);
    $('div').eq(index).fadeIn();
    $('div').not('nth-child:' + index - 1).toggle('fast');  //0 To 1 based
});
```

Comment: This was my initial thought too, but I don't think the buttons are descendants of the divs.

Answer (score 0):

or maybe what you need is [UI accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#default) ?